# How to plot data from two files?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am trying to plot the 5 first values and the 5 last of my data.
I have two files A and B.

A is order that is why I need the 5 and the five last.
I want to plot the intensity of each replicate which are in another file B.

If my names in A are found in B to plot all the values...

File B as the same rownames that file A (and more) that is why I want those in common between A and B, then if they are equal I want to plot all the values for each replicate (column) from my file B. 
So at the end I'll have 5 plots for 5first and 5 plots for 5last.

I already try something like this but like I said I am not very good with R programming.

Just to begin, I want to see if I can make the link between the two files. This doesn't work.

```
5fisrt <- A[1:5,]
5last <- A[(nrow(RT)-5+1):nrow(A), ]

i <- 0
for (i in 5fisrt)
{
  if row.names(5fisrt[i]) == row.names(B[i])
  plot <- boxplot(B,aes(B[i]))
  print (plot)
}
```

I'll function do another for 5last.

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Am I right in thinking that by “plot” you mean a scatter plot, with x-coordinates (abscissa) from a row of A, and y-coordinates (ordinate) coming from a corresponding row of B?

Comment: Yes more like a barplot actually. So I'll have 10 barplot (5first and 5 last), in x all the replicate and in y the intensities for each (that come from B).

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you want to do.  But one thing that I think is an error is that, for your for loop, "i" will index over the columns of "5first".  I think that you are trying to loop over rows, in which case you could use "1:nrow(5first)". But then, I don't even think R will let you name a variable starting with a number, so your first line of code should fail (with an error).

Comment: After choosing the rows that match the row names in A, do you want to make a boxplot for each and ever column of B?

Comment: I know I don't think I explain quiete good... My rows are 5first and 5last for A and for B the same + others rows, then in column I have several replicates (same in A and B). Once I check that I can find 5last and 5first in B, I want to make a barplot of my values for all my replicates, one plot per rows, so that I'll have 10 plot at the end. Thaks for your help!

Comment: A barplot, or a boxplot? If you want a barplot for each row, do you want the number of bars in the plot to be the number of columns in B, with the height of the bar equal to the value in that row & column?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want to make a barplot for each row in B, if the name of that row is the same as the name of one of the first 5 rows or last 5 rows of A.

If you want all 10 plots in one graphic, you can use facet_grid:

```
library(tidyverse)
n <- nrow(A)

C <- B[row.names(A[c(1:5,(n-4):n),]),]

C %>% 
  mutate(rowName = row_number()) %>% 
  gather(key = 'replicates', value = 'intensity', -rowName) %>% 
  ggplot(
    aes(
      x = replicates,
      y = intensity
    )
  ) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(rowName~.)
```

Note that my answer assumes that there are at least 10 rows in A.  The second line of code subsets B as you want, and assigns it to a new object C, just for clarity in the code.  I could have just piped that subset of B right into the mutate without defining C.

UPDATE:

Since you don't want to use facet, you could try one of these:

```
library(tidyverse)
n <- nrow(A)

C <- B[row.names(A[c(1:5,(n-4):n),]),]

D <- C %>% 
  mutate(rowName = row_number()) %>% 
  gather(key = 'replicates', value = 'intensity', -rowName)

# Plot to the RStudio viewer
for(i in 1:10){
  p <- 
    D %>% 
    filter(rowName == i) %>% 
    ggplot(
      aes(
        x = replicates,
        y = intensity
      )
    ) +
    geom_col()

    print(p)
}

# Save the plots to files
for(i in 1:10){
  p <- 
    D %>% 
    filter(rowName == i) %>% 
    ggplot(
      aes(
        x = replicates,
        y = intensity
      )
    ) +
    geom_col()

  ggsave(paste0("myPlot",i,".png"), plot = p)
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is waay better! Except that I prefer to have each plot separately because with the facet grid it is very tight and I don't the information of which rows... Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? You haven’t accepted the answer.

Comment: Yes this is perfect!! Thanks a lot Joe =)